# How do I add elements from one numpy array to another at certain indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have elements in one array that are of the form (index, value), e.g.

```
5, 20
8, 10
```

I need to add these elements into another array of a different size that initially empty, e.g.

```
X = np.zeros((1, 10))
```

and set the values of X to be the values given in the 1st array at the indices. So X, at the end, should be

```
X = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 10, 0]
```

Because the 5th element of X should be 20, and the 8th element should be 10. Is there a numpy array function that does this, or something else I can use for fast computation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`np.add.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html). Thus, assuming `X` is a `1D` array where the additions are to be stored and `A` is the array holding the indices and values to be added, you could do -

```
np.add.at(X,A[:,0],A[:,1])
```

Thus, inputs are :

```
X      : Array holding the additions
A[:,0] : Indices where additions are to be stored
A[:,1] : Values to be added
```

Sample run -

```
In [21]: A = np.array([[5,20],[8,10]])      # Indices and values

In [22]: X = np.zeros(10,dtype=A.dtype)     # Array to store additions

In [23]: np.add.at(X,A[:,0],A[:,1])         # Perform np.add.at

In [24]: X                                  # Show output
Out[24]: array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20,  0,  0, 10,  0])
```

---

If by "add", you meant that the indices are unique and you just want to "put" values, rather than "add", you could initialize the output array and index into it as shown as a sample case like so -

```
In [25]: A = np.array([[5,20],[8,10]])

In [26]: X = np.zeros(10,dtype=A.dtype)

In [27]: X[A[:,0]] = A[:,1]

In [28]: X
Out[28]: array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20,  0,  0, 10,  0])
```